# Rust can't modify RefCell in Rc

Tags: rust, rc, refcell

I want to simulate some natural process, so I have a `Simulator`, and a reactor like a `NuclearReactor`. The simulator will modify the reactor, and the reactor can reversely influance the simulator by modifying it. One important thing is that the `NuclearReactor` is wrapped from somewhere else, the `solid_function` must has a inmutable `&self`.

So after reading rust book of `RefCell`, I wrote something like these:

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

pub struct Simulator {
    nr: NuclearReactor,
    data: Vec<f64>,
}

impl Simulator {
    pub fn on_nuclear_data(&mut self, x: i64) {
        // modify self
    }
    pub fn run_simulation(&mut self) {}
}

pub struct NuclearReactor {
    simulator: Option<Weak<RefCell<Simulator>>>,
}

impl NuclearReactor {
    pub fn solid_function(&self, x: i64) {
        /*
        this function `&self` is solid, so I have to use a RefCell to wrap Simulator
         */
    }

    pub fn write_simulator(&self) {
        /*
        none of the two following snippets will work
         */

        /* snippet1: compiler says:
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
  --> src/main.rs:87:17
   |
87 |         let t = *self.simulator.unwrap().upgrade().unwrap();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 move occurs because value has type `RefCell<Simulator>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                 help: consider borrowing here: `&*self.simulator.unwrap().upgrade().unwrap()`

        */
        let t = *self.simulator.unwrap().upgrade().unwrap();
        t.borrow_mut().on_nuclear_data(0);

        /*
         snippet2: compiler says:
error[E0599]: no method named `on_nuclear_data` found for mutable reference `&mut Rc<RefCell<Simulator>>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:101:65
    |
101 |         self.simulator.unwrap().upgrade().unwrap().borrow_mut().on_nuclear_data(0);
    |                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Rc<RefCell<Simulator>>`

         */
        // self.simulator.unwrap().upgrade().unwrap().borrow_mut().on_nuclear_data(0);
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let nr_ = NuclearReactor {
        simulator: None
    };


    let mut sm_ = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Simulator {
        nr: nr_,
        data: vec![],
    }));


    (*sm_).borrow_mut().nr.simulator = Some(Rc::downgrade(&sm_));
}
```

But it won't compile. How should I solve it.

---

Oh... the compile hints me solved it. But it seems complicated. Can anyone explain that, or give a better pattern? I think the pattern is common.

```
        let t = &*self.simulator.as_ref().unwrap().upgrade().unwrap();
        t.borrow_mut().on_nuclear_data(0);
```

---

Actually it should be:

```
    (*self.simulator.as_ref().unwrap().upgrade().unwrap()).borrow_mut().on_nuclear_data(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `&Option<T>` cannot be `unwrap`ped.

`self.simulator`, where `self` is a `&Self`, gets a `&Option<Weak<RefCell<Simulator>>>`.

`Option<T>::unwrap` consumes the `self` and return the inner value by 'move'.

`Option<T>::as_ref` converts `&self` into an `Option<&T>` safely so that you can `unwrap` into a `&T`.