# rust two objects refering each borrow_mut pattern

Tags: rust, refcell

A similar question I posted earlier is here
[Rust can't modify RefCell in Rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611704/rust-cant-modify-refcell-in-rc/72611809#72611809), but completely different.

---

I want to simulate some natural process, so I have a `Simulator`, and a reactor like a `NuclearReactor`. The simulator will modify the reactor, and the reactor can reversely influance the simulator by modifying it. One important thing is that the `NuclearReactor` is wrapped from somewhere else, the `solid_function` must has a inmutable `&self`.

So after reading rust book of `RefCell`, I wrote something like these, It complies, but crashed.

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

pub struct Simulator {
    nr: NuclearReactor,
    data: Vec<f64>,
}

impl Simulator {
    pub fn on_nuclear_data(&mut self, x: i64) {
        // modify self
    }
    pub fn run_simulation(&mut self) {
        self.nr.write_simulator();
    }
}

pub struct NuclearReactor {
    simulator: Option<Weak<RefCell<Simulator>>>,
}

impl NuclearReactor {
    pub fn solid_function(&self, x: i64) {
        /*
        this function `&self` is solid, so I have to use a RefCell to wrap Simulator
         */
    }

    pub fn write_simulator(&self) {
        /*
        thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'
        */
        (*self.simulator.as_ref().unwrap().upgrade().unwrap()).borrow_mut().on_nuclear_data(0);
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let nr_ = NuclearReactor {
        simulator: None
    };

    let mut sm_ = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Simulator {
        nr: nr_,
        data: vec![],
    }));


    (*sm_).borrow_mut().nr.simulator = Some(Rc::downgrade(&sm_));
    (*sm_).borrow_mut().run_simulation();
}
```

Obviously, the runtime check of `borrow_mut` fails.

Actually the `NuclearReactor` is my online code, the `Simulator` is an offline test, so I wanna modify the `NuclearReactor` at a minimal cost to let it run on the offline environment. That's why I have to keep the  function `solid_function`  with an immutable `&self`. Changing it to a `&mut self` is and then move `to-modifying objects` to a seperate function is feasible, but then I have to modify the online code frequently at a high cost. It there anything cool that can solve it ?

Comment: The easiest solution is to remove the `simulator` field from `NuclearReactor` and instead pass it as a parameter to the methods that need it, e.g.: `pub fn write_simulator (&self, simulator: &mut Simulator)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after reading this: http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/11/01/after-nll-interprocedural-conflicts/

I finnaly realized that what I am doing is something like below and rust was helping me avoiding bugs.

```
let v: Vec<i64> = vec![1,2,3];
for ele in v.iter_mut(){
    v.push(1);
}
```

Thankfully, pushing `NuclearReactor`'s modify to a temp buffer then apply them to `Simulator` is just enough to solve my problem.

Also, I didn't explain the question clearly (actually I didn't get the point to describe the question until I solved it), so the community can't help me.